# Is there a way to highlight a cell if it contains same word/s from another column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm manually cross checking a bunch of data to see if a cell in column 1 contains at least one same word from column 2. If it does, I usually just bold the cell in column 1 to leave a trail.

For example, in column 1, the content of the cell is "World Option" and in column 2 it contains "worldoption", since the cell in column 1 contains at least one same word basing from column 2, I will then bold it. Here's an actual sample: https://prnt.sc/EM40fy0aI_tO

Is there a formula in Conditional Formatting for doing this automatically?

Comment: Perhaps mention Google Sheets in the question title, or in the first sentence, so it is more obvious? Great answer! :)